# how can I convert a2c3d to accfd?

Tags: python

here we just have to add the num written to the previous character ascii value .

I tried that

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = input()
    list1 = list(n)
    for i in list1:
        if list1[i] is not chr:
            list1[i] = list1[i-1] + list1[i]

    print(list(n))
```

Comment: whats the output you are getting now?

Answer (score 1):

This approach has the advantage to not use a list. It stores the previous char in the `prev` variable to use in case of a digit.

```
text = 'a2c3d'
result = ''
prev = None
for ch in text:
    if ch.isdigit() and prev:
        result += chr(int(ch) + ord(prev))
    else:
        result += ch
        prev = ch
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You iterate the given string, if it is a character you add it to a list. if not you take the `ord()` of the last char in your list and add the number. you stick all together at the end:

```
def change(t):
    rv = [] # accumulates all characters
    for c in t: # iterate all characters in t
        if c.isdigit(): # if a digit
            if not rv:    # and no characters in rv: error
                raise ValueError("Cant have number before character")
            rv.append(chr(ord(rv[-1])+int(c))) # else append the number to the last char
        else:
            rv.append(c) # not a number, simply append

    return ''.join(rv) # join all characters again

print(change("a2c3d"))
```

Output:

```
accfd
```